# How to pass Bitbucket pipeline repository variables to npm run script?

Tags: npm, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines, npm-scripts, docker-image

How do I pass a Bitbucket repository variable into the Cypress.io test script that I am running with `npm run` in a pipeline?

The pipeline and tests work, but I am unable to get a Bitbucket variable into the test file iteself.  I can access the respository variable from `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` following the instructions provided by Bitbucket on the repository variable page, but I cannot access the variable inside of `cypress/integration/example.js`.  I want to store credentials the test scripts use as Bitbucket repository variables.

Here's my code...

**bitbucket-pipeline.yml**

```
image: cypress/included:3.2.0

pipelines:
  custom:
    robot:
      - step:
          script:
            - printenv
            - npm ci
            - npm run e2e
```

- uses an image provided by Cypress
- I can see my repository variables via `printenv`

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "cypress run"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.4.1"
  }
}
```

**cypress/integration/example.js**

```
describe('A', () => {
  it('should B', () => {
    cy.visit('https://google.com');
  });
});
```

- I want to use the Bitbucket repository variable inside of the `it('should B' ...)` method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Cypress.io documentation on environment variables:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables

**bitbucket-pipeline.yml**

```
image: cypress/included:3.2.0

pipelines:
  custom:
    robot:
      - step:
          script:
            - npm ci
            - export CYPRESS_example=$example
            - export CYPRESS_whatever=$whatever
            - npm run e2e
```

Where **example** is the name of the Bitbucket repo variable.  Might be case sensitive.

Add **$** to reference the Bitbucket repository variable in the `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` file.

Use **CYPRESS_** to identify it as a Cypress environment variable.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_

Then you can use it in the test spec via `Cypress.env("example")`

I actually had to typecast because Bitbucket was providing unexpected data types...

```
cy.get('[name="password"]').clear().type(Cypress.env("example").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin to have a profiles for each deployment and when run the script you can set which env to run the script for example below would work if plugin setup properly inside the pipeline.

npx cypress run --env version="qa"
npx cypress run --env version="prod"